# JQuery Validate AJAX > undefined has no properties

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

Sorry, i posted it before finished the whole text..

I get an Error after clicking the SUBMIT-Button:

**ERRORLOG**

```
TypeError: undefined has no properties
[Weitere Informationen]
jquery.validate.min.js:4:22946
a.ajax
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js:4:22946
submitHandler
http://suedsicht-projekte.de/opus/newsletter-daten/landingpage/js/main.js:13:7
d
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js:4:962
validate/<
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js:4:1173
dispatch
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3:10499
add/q.handle
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3:8561
```

**the script worked on an other site. But this time it dont work :(**

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#teilnahme").validate({
    rules: {
      inputVorname: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
      inputVorname: { required: "Bitte tragen Sie Ihren Vornamen ein." }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      theUrl = 'teilnahme.php';
      var params = $(form).serialize();

      $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: theUrl,
        data: params,
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
          $("#sendbutton").fadeOut(100).hide(function(){
          $("#successbutton").fadeIn(100).show(function(){
          $(".result").html(data);
          });
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }); //end validate
});
```

Validation Work. But the submitHandler doesnt

**HTML**

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" name="teilnahme" id="teilnahme">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputVorname">Vorname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputVorname" name="inputVorname" placeholder="Vorname">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputNachname">Nachname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNachname" name="inputNachname" placeholder="Nachname">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputFirm">Firma</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirm" name="inputFirm" placeholder="Firma">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputAddress">Address 2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" name="inputAddress" placeholder="Straße">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="inputPLZ">Postleitzahl</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPLZ" name="inputPLZ">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputCity">Stadt</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" name="inputCity">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">Bundesland</label>
        <select id="inputState" name="inputState" class="form-control">
          <option selected>Baden-Württemberg</option>
          <option>...</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">2 Übernachtungen, Anreise am Vortag</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">1 Übernachtung, Anreise am 27.04</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="customRadio3" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio3">1 Übernachtung</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="customRadio4" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio4">Ohne Übernachtung</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="sendbutton" class="btn btn-success">Teilnehmen</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="successbutton" disabled="disabled"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
  </form>
```

I had to explain more... 
So i want an simple form. If i click the submit-button all information has to go to the "teilnahme.php" where a php-script will import all to a mySQL database. 
Maybe there is an other solution for that. I have no idea.

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but you should remove `async: false`. It's very, very bad practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I notice in your error message a reference to jQuery slim:

`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js`

jQuery slim does not include the $.ajax() or any other associated functions.

If you wish to use ajax functionality, you need to use the full version of jQuery.

See the latest (at the time of writing) release notes for details of what is and is not included in the "slim" build: https://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/20/jquery-3-2-1-now-available/

Comment: Thanks, i think that was one of the MAIN-Problems.
But i get a new one:

**ReferenceError: data is not defined:**

`success/</<
http://suedsicht-projekte.de/opus/newsletter-daten/landingpage/js/main.js:21:11
r.speed/d.complete
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3:29099
i
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:28012
fireWith
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:28783
i
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3:27367
r.fx.tick
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3:30808
eb
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3:25065`

Comment: i deleted the async:false (a comment below said that it is better to remove. If i add it, it worked :/

Comment: @Daniel I think your line should probably be `$(".result").html(result);`. Otherwise you just write back the some other random data (not sure where from?) surely? And that would also be why `data` is not defined when the call is async, because it's not part of the response. The comment is right, there is no good reason to use `async: false` in 99.9% of cases - it just locks up the browser and rarely achieves anything useful. Also some browsers have deprecated its use so you could expect it to stop working at all in future. Async ajax is a good thing, you just have to grok the callback concept.